# GCM onRegistered() method

Tags: android, push-notification, registration

I have seen the "GCM Architectural Overview" from http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html. The doc says that when an android app registers for GCM, the onRegistered(Context c,String regId) is called containing the regId which then user sends to its server. The doc says that "Google may periodically refresh the registration ID". My question is how should I know that Google has refreshed regId for user?

One thing that comes into my mind is that when id is refreshed, it again fires the **com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION** intent resulting in to a call to onRegistered() method. Am I right? If so, then I can resend regId to my server.

Answer (score 0):

google not notify u about change of regid u have to periodically check the regid and send to your server

Comment: You mean that if my id is changed/refreshed, I will get blank regId on  a call to GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId() and I will again make a call to GCMRegistrar.register(this, PROJECT_ID) and will get new ID and will send an update request to my server. Is this the way you are saying?

Comment: save regid in sharedpreference first time  u got reg id the by async or other method check again if regid change resend to ur server again periodically